# android UI change from another thread

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a simple music player in android but my problem is that when trying to update the UI (eg. changing a textview which displays the current position of the song that is being played) it doesn't change smoothly if I use another thread. My problem with a timer is that in the run method I can't change the UI directly. Anyone any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a TextView rather than something like a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)? It seems to me like a bar would be more natural for this purpose.

Answer (score 7):

you cant update UI directly in thread and but you can change UI in thread using `runOnUiThread` method..

like this..

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run()
 {
       TextView.setText("hiiiiiiiii");
 }});
```

Comment: I tried this. But the text still doesn't change smoothly. Sometimes one second is just skipped. It seems like it had to be updtated even faster but if i update very fast then the whole program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

From the non UI thread send a Broadcast Intent & populate it with the variables required by the UI & then send it. In the UI thread implement a Broadcast Receiver & let the UI thread update itself.